# Push ads to the bottom on large screens

Tags: android, screen, ads

Basically it's a page of text and pics with ads at the bottom. It works fine on smaller devices like phones, but on larger like tablets there is a problem....more of a user dislike thing.

If the content of page is small then ads, which comes correctly at the end of content actually comes in the middle of the screen.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vnaslov"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vautor"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vnaslov"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vdatum"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/vautor"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vnaslov"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vlid"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vdatum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     />

<com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
    android:id="@+id/vslika"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vlid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
     />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vtijelo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vslika"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"  />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/videobutton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vtijelo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/dugme_video"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

 <com.google.ads.doubleclick.DfpAdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

It works if it's simple like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="But1" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="But2" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>`
```

But not if it's filled with my content like the above in my question. First linearlayout with content up to the ad, and second with just the ad...

How would the content inside linearlayout be a problem?

Why?

Comment: there might be an issue with your layout design,if you are using relative layout as parent of advertisement layout.Use layout_alignParentBottom.Post your xml layout file here.

Comment: it would be nice if it could go to the bottom only when the content is smaller then screen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use layout_weight="1" and fillViewport="true" on the ScrollView.

This should do the trick:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativemain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollmain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/wrap"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                //put your content here

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/myadv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                //this is your advertisement

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i dont want ads on bottom all the time. just if content is smaller then the screen..

Comment: still the same..ads come after content and if content is short there is a lot of empty space left after.

Comment: i even copied all of your code line by line..on my nexus 7 it does not work

Comment: I can assure the code works wonderfully, tested on HTC Desire, Motorola Razr I and Asus TF300T

Comment: i think those do not have 4.4.2? my nexus 7 does...could it be that fillViewport don't work correctly o 4.4.2?

Comment: and scrolView.setFillViewport(true) also dont make a difference

Comment: i'm sorry..this is my bad. it works of course...its the thing when you trust yourself to much. i never edited xml for large screen layout, only for small/regular one...stupid, stupid, stupid            Just realized that now when tying to do some other layout change :)